# NGINX: Block "wp-login.php", but allow "wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=..."

Tags: nginx, http, wordpress, http-headers

I'm blocking access to `wp-login.php` via NGINX like this (only one IP address is allowed):

```
location ~ ^/wp-login.php {
    allow 12.12.12.12;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Now I have the following problem: There's also WooCommerce running on that WordPress installation. That means, that when a woocommerce customers logs out from his backend, he's doing this through the following address:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faccount%2F&_wpnonce=xxxxxxxx
```

Right now, with the current configuration, the WooCommerce customer received a `403` as well, which is not good at all. As you can see, `wp-login.php` must be open if we have the `GET` parameter `action=logout`. What I have tried so far (which is not working, still getting a `403`):

```
location ~ ^/wp-login.php {

    error_page 460 = @woologout;
    if ( $query_string = "action=logout" ) { return 460; }

    allow 12.12.12.12;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location @woologout {
    allow all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can block `wp-login.php` to everyone, but have `wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faccount%2F&_wpnonce=xxxxxxxx` world-open? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Create a location block which matches wp-login.php. If the action is not "logout" then return a `403` code.

```
location ~ wp-login.php
{
    if ($arg_action != logout) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

To permit a certain IP address to make a "wp-login.php" request, try this code, which uses a variable to check the IP address and the query string conditions:

```
location ~ wp-login.php
{
    if ($arg_action != logout) {
        set $block_components Y;
    }

    if ($remote_addr != <IP-ADDRESS>) {
        set $block_components "${block_components}Y";
    }

    if ($block_components = YY) {
        return 403;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this blocks all traffic - but how do I still allow one certain IP to access `wp-login.php` without having `action=logout` in the URL?

Comment: did you comment out  your `location ~ ^/wp-login.php {` block before trying this? I've tested it on my system.

Comment: Yes it works, but it blocks all traffic now as I mentioned in my previous comment - do you know how do I still allow one certain IP to access `wp-login.php` without having `action=logout` in the URL?

Comment: See updated post, I've not been able to test though the syntax has been checked.